# Why the background image in this website changes over time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does this background image work?

This is the website:
https://www.kuaizero.com/

Comment: I expect there's some code involved

Comment: I wish I  can learn about it.
So I can do it myself:(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its a background video in the div "SITE_BACKGROUND", video is in the url:

https://video.wixstatic.com/video/11062b_456cb078f5fb4deaa2845361aa665cf0/1080p/mp4/file.mp4

Comment: glad to help. :)